# How to buffer the video and save in local database in iOS app?

Tags: ios, database, core-data, video, video-streaming

I am creating an app in which I have a link to download the video of size around 50 MB and play as well. When user will tap on the link, the video should start buffering (like in YouTube) and should get save in the local database. I was trying to run a separate thread for each task. One thread will buffer and another will download the video and save in the local database, but it was increasing the memory allocation hugely as the size of video is around 50 MB so is there any way to achieve this task, I mean playing the video and saving it locally? Can I save the video data as it buffers. Please let me know if there is any sample app for this purpose and also let me know if I am unclear at any point.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem would be slightly different to yours.

I would download and save any videos as files, and only store their locations in your Core Data database. The video player on the main thread can then be directed at the local file that is being downloaded, presumably in another thread.

Comment: That is fine but my query is that if it is possible to play the video while it is downloading?